# Как вывести елочку в консоли на golang?

Tags: golang

Используя вложенные циклы необходимо вывести елочку симметричную. Задача стоит следующая:
Вывод ёлочки.

```
Введите высоту ёлочки:
5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, второй день не могу понять. Желательно с детальным объяснением. Я только учусь

Comment: *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть на требуемый результат с конца, то можно заметить, что количество пробелов перед выводимой строкой изменяется на 1. Поэтому для простоты можно использовать обратный цикл.

Количество `*` при итерации цикла меняется на 2 - `1 3 5 .. n+2`

Для формирования строки из повторяющихся символов нам понадобится функция `strings.Repeat`.

```
func printTree(height int) {
    chars := 1 // начальное кол-во * в строке
    for i := height; i > 0; i-- {
        line := strings.Repeat("*", chars) // формируем строку состоящую из *
        indent := strings.Repeat(" ", i)   // добавляем отступы
        fmt.Printf("%s%s\n", indent, line) // выводим строку в консоль
        chars += 2                         // увеличиваем кол-во звёздочек на 2
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

https://go.dev/play/p/3Tn-qADePyo